# Creating 60s strips from ecg signal recording ( .bat ) file and give it a label as per the datapoint present in it

Tags: signal-analysis, scipy, ecg

I am working with https://physionet.org/content/mitdb/1.0.0/ dataset where we have 48 ecg signal files.

Each recording is 30 minutes long and I Want to create 60s strips and give it a label. ie based on patient ECG condition and data points present in signal label it as `normal, afib, ventricular or other`

I have written code that reads signal, creates 60s strips and assign a label as per the data point present in it.

**Problem I have, strips I am getting are not correct, so if anyone has used arrhythmia or mit-bih data can understand what wrong with this code.**

I have tried doing this but I doubt my logic is correct.

```
label2num={ 'A':1,'+':2, 'N':3, 'a':4, '"':5, '(AFIB':6}
import glob
#Here we assign label to strips as per the datapoint present in it
def PickLabel(row):
    if(label2num['A'] in row or label2num['a'] in row ): # If one label is A, assign it to A 
      return 'A'
    elif(np.allclose(row, label2num['N'])): ## If all labels are 'N'
      return "N"
    elif label2num['N'] in row and (label2num['+'] not in row or label2num['"']not in row) and  0  in row :
      return "N"
    else:  # Else other.
      return 'O'
#Read the recording,create the strips 
def ProcessOneFile(filename,Tw):
  
  sig, fields = wfdb.rdsamp(filename, channels=[0])
  sig=sig[:,0]
  lenn=int(len(sig)/19200)
  res=lenn*19200
  sig=sig[:res]
  sig_frames=np.reshape(sig,(-1,Tw*320)) # Tw- time window, 320-sample rate # frame signal (non-overlapping frames)
  annotation = wfdb.rdann(filename, 'atr')
  loc=annotation.__dict__['sample']
  valid_indicies=loc<sig.shape[0]  ## Just to make sure the label position doesn't exceed the length
  loc=loc[valid_indicies]
  symbol=np.array(annotation.__dict__['symbol'])
  print(np.unique(symbol))
  symbol=symbol[valid_indicies]
  print(len(annotation.__dict__['symbol']))
  print(len(annotation.__dict__['aux_note']))
  symbol_num=np.array([label2num.get(x,0) for x in symbol])  # To handle unknown symbol (the returned value will be zero)
  symbol_arr=np.zeros(sig.shape)
  symbol_arr[loc]=symbol_num
  lenn2=int(len(symbol_arr)/19200)
  res2=lenn2*19200
  symbol_arr=symbol_arr[:res]
  symbol_arr_frames=np.reshape(symbol_arr,(-1,Tw*320))  # frame symbols (non-overlapping frames)
  labels=np.apply_along_axis(PickLabel, 1, symbol_arr_frames)    # apply PickLabel function to each row
  return sig_frames,labels,symbol_arr_frames, symbol,valid_indicies

sig_frames,labels,symbol_arr_frames,symbol,valid_indicies=ProcessOneFile(files_dir+'/219',Tw)
```

Comment: Would you care to provide some more information? What is **not** working, what exactly are you trying to achieve with this code snippet (how is the labelling done, etc.)? This way, it will be easier for the people here to provide some helpful solutions and/or insight on the problem.

Comment: Sure @ZaellixA : let me edit the explanation